# Clone a repository, then update from changes in original

Tags: git

I would like to have a repository act as a project template. I could then clone that template any time I want to start a new project.

This is similar to just having branches, but I would like to separate the repos for the base project, and the resulting projects.

A fork also does not seem like the correct strategy, as this is meant to eventually be re-merged into the template, and does not disconnect the projects like I am envisioning.

I have researched a few options, like merge vs. rebase, but do not want to over-write the branches of the new projects with the branches of the original.

I am looking for a tried-and-true method for this. I am also open to other philosophies on handling this scenario in a better fashion...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am looking into 'Submodules' as a solution. The idea of 'loosely-coupled repositories' is similar to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing:

```
git remote add 'TemplateName' Repo_URL
git fetch 'TemplateName'
git merge 'TemplateName'/master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

After handling merge conflicts, this brings the master branch into whichever project may have needed the update.